# Tensorflow Graph level seed

Tags: tensorflow, graph, seed

I have a checkpoint file of an existing network. I have some of the hyper parameters used in the network but I do not have the seed value. I restored the network and printed all_vars below and it prints out the values, but it does not contain the value of the graph level seed. I tried printing tf.Graph.seed but it just outputs . 
Here is the snippet of code I ran:

```
sess = tf.Session()
saved_net = tf.train.import_meta_graph("c:/log/model.ckpt-0.meta")
saved_net = saved_sess.restore(sess, "c:/log/model.ckpt-0")
all_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)
print(all_vars)

print("seed")
print(tf.Graph.seed)
```

Is there a way to get the graph level seed value from a saved network?

Comment: Sorry I have a type in there. The third line is saved_sess = saved_net.restore(....)

Comment: Seems like a line was truncated. When I run print(tf.Graph.seed) it outputs <property object at 0x00000000118D0F98>.